# Erlang supervisor exception on starting worker

Tags: exception, erlang, erlang-supervisor

I'm playing with code for supervisor trees taken from http://learnyousomeerlang.com/building-applications-with-otp but I get a noproc exception that I can't figure out when I try to get a supervisor to start the child process. This is my shell interaction:

```
   1>  application:start(test).
root supervisor init
ok
    2> test_sup:start_service(service_sup,{service_worker, start_link,[]}).
{ok,<0.39.0>}
   worker supervisor initialise (M: service_worker,F: start_link,A: []) 

    3> test_app:run(service_worker,[]). 
  server run: (name: service_worker args: []) 
    ** exception exit: {noproc,{gen_server,call,[service_worker,{run,[]}]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 182)
```

Code is:

```
-module(test_app).
-behaviour(application).
-export([start/2, stop/1, run/2]).

start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->
    test_sup:start_link().


run(Name, Args) ->
    service_serv:run(Name, Args).
```

=====

```
-module(test_sup).

-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0, init/1, stop/0, start_service/2, stop_service/1]). 

-define(CHILD(I, Type), {I, {I, start_link, []}, permanent, 5000, Type, [I]}).
start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, service}, ?MODULE, []).

init([]) ->
    io:format("root supervisor init~n"),
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 5, 10},
        []}}.

start_service(Name, MFA) ->
    ChildSpec = {Name,
                 {service_sup, start_link, [Name, MFA]},
                  permanent, 10500, supervisor, [service_sup]},
    io:format("start service supervisor (Name: ~p, MFA: ~p): ", [Name, MFA]),
    supervisor:start_child(service, ChildSpec). 
[snip]
```

====

```
-module(service_sup).
-export([start_link/2, init/1]).
-behaviour(supervisor).

start_link(Name, MFA) ->
    supervisor:start_link(?MODULE, {Name, MFA}).

init({Name, MFA}) ->
    MaxRestart = 1,
    MaxTime = 3600,
    {ok, {{one_for_all, MaxRestart, MaxTime},
          [{serv,
             {service_serv, start_link, [Name, self(), MFA]}, 
             permanent,
             5000,
             worker, [service_serv]}]}}.
```

========

```
-module(worker_sup).
-export([start_link/1, init/1]).
-behaviour(supervisor).

start_link(MFA) ->
    supervisor:start_link(?MODULE, MFA).

init({M,F,A}) ->
    {ok, {{simple_one_for_one, 5, 3600},
          [{service_worker,
            {M,F,A},
            temporary, 5000, worker, [M]}]}}.
```

===

```
-module(service_serv). 

-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start/3, start_link/3, run/2,
         status/1, ping/1, stop/1]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
         code_change/3, terminate/2]).

-define(WORKER_SUP_SPEC(MFA),
        {worker_sup,
         {worker_sup, start_link, [MFA]},
          permanent,
          10000,
          supervisor,
          [worker_sup]}).        


-record(state, {sup,
                refs,
                queue=queue:new()
                }). 

start(Name, Sup, MFA) when is_atom(Name) ->
    gen_server:start({local, Name}, ?MODULE, {MFA, Sup}, []).                     

start_link(Name, Sup, MFA) when is_atom(Name) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, Name}, ?MODULE, {MFA, Sup}, []).  

init({MFA, Sup}) ->
    self() ! {start_worker_supervisor, Sup, MFA},
    {ok, #state{}}.

run(Name, Args) ->
    io:format("server run: (name: ~p args: ~p) ~n",[Name, Args]),
    gen_server:call(Name, {run, Args}).

handle_info({start_worker_supervisor, Sup, MFA}, S = #state{}) ->
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_child(Sup, ?WORKER_SUP_SPEC(MFA)),
    {noreply, S#state{sup=Pid}};
handle_info({'DOWN', Ref, process, _Pid, _}, S = #state{refs=Refs}) ->
    case gb_sets:is_element(Ref, Refs) of
        true ->
            handle_down_worker(Ref, S);
        false -> %% Not our responsibility
            {noreply, S}
    end;    
handle_info(Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_call({run, Args}, _From, S = #state{sup=Sup, refs=R}) ->
    io:format("handle run call ~n"),
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_child(Sup, Args),
    Ref = erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
    {reply, {ok, run, Pid}, S#state{refs=gb_sets:add(Ref,R)}};
[snip]
```

====

```
-module(service_worker).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([start_link/4, stop/1]).
-export([init/0, init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2,
         handle_info/2, code_change/3, terminate/2]).

start_link(Task, Delay, Max, SendTo) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, {Task, Delay, Max, SendTo} , []).

stop(Pid) ->
    gen_server:call(Pid, stop).

init({Task, Delay, Max, SendTo}) ->
    io:format("initialise worker ~n"),
%%  {ok, {Task, Delay, Max, SendTo}}.
    {ok, {Task, Delay, Max, SendTo}, Delay}.
```

[snip]

Comment: The messages in the output (`worker supervisor initialise` and `server run`) don't seem to be found in the code.  Is this the most up-to-date version?

Comment: I chopped some io:format stuff out for clarity but it's the latest problem code.

Answer (score 2):

The volume of code you've produced is a little difficult to parse, but what stands out to me most is that you are apparently using the atom "service_worker" to refer to the process that you start.

This is all well and good if you register a process with that atom (either by calling `erlang:register(service_worker, Pid)` or starting the process with `gen_server:start_link({local, service_worker}, ?MODULE, Args, Opts)`). You appear to be doing neither, and the error message you receive supports that assessment.

```
** exception exit: {noproc,{gen_server,call,[service_worker,{run,[]}]}}
 in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 182)
```

What this error tells us is that `gen_server:call` was not able to find the process (`noproc`). The arguments to `gen_server:call` are included in the error message, and in the spot where one would expect to find the `Pid`, we find instead `service_worker`.

Additionally, your `service_worker` module appears to be started by a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor. Such supervisors are used when you need multiple of the same "type" of process (e.g., same callback module). Such supervisors also do not start workers on their own (you must invoke `supervisor:start_child(SupPid, ExtraArgs)`).

Those are the two main issues I see with your present attempt. For a quick and dirty fix, try adding `{local, service_worker}` or `{local, ?MODULE}` as the first argument to the `gen_server:start_link` call in the service_worker module. Please bear in mind that this will not work if you intend to start multiple service_worker processes (as only one process can be registered to an atom at a time).