# Erlang: OTP - properly passing children arguments; workers exiting with exceptions

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a supervisor / worker tree organized as follows:

```
game_super -> {keyserver: worker, loginserver: super}
loginserver -> loginlistener: worker (socket pool)
```

The key server works okay. It just returns the string of random bytes it uses to construct login tokens. It is periodically replaced.

My login server use to work under R16. Then I upgraded to R18 because I wanted to use maps. IDK if that is the issue... I doubt it though. The other change I made is the reason I need maps was for the convenience of setting up children.

I have multiple redis servers, each with their own purpose. One is rate limiting. That's the only one operating right now. I call `game_core:redis_init()` in `game_supervisor:init([])`. It returns `{ok,{#MapPids, #MapScriptKeys}`. Where `#MapScriptKeys` values are tuples containing all Sha hashes of LUA scripts.

I'm getting `exception exit: {shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,login,<0.178.0>}}` Pids obviously change but that was the last result after calling `game_supervisor:start_inshell()`.

I've inserted an `io:format("~p\n",[State]),` just before the `{ok, State}` in `login_listener:init(State)` and it prints out everything... once. Considering that's right before returning.... how does it fail?

The code is based on: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/buckets-of-sockets

Is this similar to: [Erlang supervisor exception on starting worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161837/erlang-supervisor-exception-on-starting-worker) , where the same name was reused for children?

**Game Supervisor**

```
-module(game_supervisor).
-behavior(supervisor).

-include("constants.hrl").

-export([start/0, start/1, start_inshell/0, init/1]).

start(Args) ->
    spawn(fun() ->
            supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Args)
        end).

start_inshell() ->
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []),
    unlink(Pid).

start() -> start([]).

init([]) ->
    {ok, RedisState} = game_core:redis_init(),
    {ok, {
        {one_for_one, 2, 10}, [ %more than 2 restarts w/i 10 seconds all killed
        {key,
            {key_server, start_link, []},
            permanent,
            10000,
            worker,
            [key_server]},
        {login,
            {login_server, start_link, [RedisState]},
            permanent,
            10000,
            supervisor,
            [login_server]}%,
%       {game,
%           {game_server, start_link, [RedisState]},
%           permanent,
%           10000,
%           supervisor,
%           [game_server]}
    ]}}.
```

**Login Server**

```
-module(login_server).
-behavior(supervisor).

-include("constants.hrl").

-export([start_link/0, start_link/1, init/1, start_socket/0]).

start_link(Args) ->
    spawn(fun() ->
            supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Args)
    end).

start_link() -> start_link([]).

init({Pid,Scripts}) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:listen(?PORT_LISTEN_LOGIN, [{active,once}, {reuseaddr, true}]),

    %Construct socket pool
    spawn_link(fun start_pool/0),

    %Put all redis information for login clients here
    RedisState = {maps:get(limiter,Pid),maps:get(limiter,Scripts)},

    %Child specification
    {ok, {
        {simple_one_for_one, 2, 10}, [  %more than 2 restarts w/i 10 seconds all killed
        {listener,
            {login_listener, start_link, [{Socket, RedisState}]},
            temporary,
            1000,
            worker,
            [login_listener]}
    ]}}.

start_pool() ->
    [start_socket() || _ <- lists:seq(1,32)],
    ok.

start_socket() -> supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, []).
```

**Login Handler**

```
-module(login_listener).
-behavior(gen_server).

-include("constants.hrl").

-export([start_link/1]).

%required callbacks
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

start_link(State) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, State,[]).

init(State) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    gen_server:cast(self(), accept),
    {ok, State}.

handle_cast(accept, State) ->                   %Param(s): Msg, State
    {Socket, RedisState} = State,

    {ok, AcceptSocket} = gen_tcp:accept(Socket),
    login_server:start_socket(),
    {noreply, {AcceptSocket, RedisState}}.

handle_info({tcp, Socket, Str}, State) ->           %Param(s): Info
    %%Login
    {_, {PidLimiter,{ShaLimiter}}} = State,
    {ok, {ClientIP, _ }} = inet:peername(Socket),

    {ok, Result} = game_core:rate_limit(PidLimiter, ShaLimiter, ClientIP),

    ok = inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
    {noreply, State}.

%%Surpress warnings
handle_call(_, _, State) -> {noreply, State}.       %Param(s): Request, From
terminate(_, _) -> ok.                              %Param(s): Reason, State
code_change(_, State,_) -> {ok, State}.         %Param(s): OldVsn, Extra
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are your supervisor start functions calling `spawn/1`? For `game_supervisor`, change this:

```
start(Args) ->
    spawn(fun() ->
            supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Args)
        end).
```

to this:

```
start(Args) ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Args).
```

And for `login_server`, change this:

```
start_link(Args) ->
    spawn(fun() ->
            supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Args)
    end).
```

to this:

```
start_link(Args) ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Args).
```

Comment: Thank you. Wish I understand the internals more. Glad I tried it before I typed something. This didn't seem to cause a problem before when I was only passing the socket... but then again that was R16. There is no good reason why (ignorance).... just copied the style from pg. 398 "Programming Erlang, 2nd Ed"